# Windows Kiosk mode no virtual keyboard after killing explorer.exe

Tags: windows, windows-10, kiosk, virtual-keyboard

I am having a problem when trying to use a Windows 10 tablet as a `Kiosk` and after I kill the `explorer.exe` the keyboard doesn't appear.

I am having a major problem here because killing `explorer.exe` is a must.

Did anyone else have any solutions? By the way, the new keyboard of windows has a spanner with options which allows the user to use windows functions and in `Kiosk Mode`, this is a killer.

Comment: virtual keyboard relies on explorer to run. Any way to connect a wireless keyboard?

Comment: the windows tablets are placed on protected case so people can add comments with virtual keyboard, so no physical keyboard will be there i was wandering is there any way to extract dependency of 'TabTip' from explorer?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by killing explorer.exe?